# Proper Join query from three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have four tables:

```
categories table ->idcat(int), cat(varchar); 
topics table     ->idtopic(int), topic(varchar), idcat(int-fk), iduser(int-fk); 
replies table    ->idreply(int), reply(varchar) iduser(int-fk), idtopic(int-fk)
users table      ->iduser(int), username(varchar).
```

I am trying to write a SQL query with JOIN to get `topic`, `user` and number of `replies`.  I have a query that gets `topic` and `iduser` but don't know how to write it to extract `user` (instead of `iduser`) and `replies` for the topic (join somehow on idtopic) all in the same query.  Help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, t.iduser 
FROM topics t 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'";
```

$idcat is one of the 4 'idcat' variables that are passed.

Comment: So, having [read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) for JOIN queries, what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: It seems like what you want is to add fields from categories table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `iduser` in table `topics` is the id of the user who created the topic? If yes, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username, COUNT(r.idreply) AS cnt
FROM topics t 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'"
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser
LEFT JOIN replies r ON t.idtopic = r.idtopic
GROUP BY t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username;
```

Comment: Great...this query brings in the proper join to get the 'username'.  Tnx...  Any idea how I can add to the query to the # of replies for  the topic as well?

Comment: This is what i have tried to include replies into the query without success.  $query = "SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username r.idreply FROM topics t LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat LEFT JOIN users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser LEFT JOIN idreply r ON r.idtopic = t.idtopic WHERE c.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'";

Comment: Maybe I got you a little wrong here. I edited my answer again. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I'm a newbie.  You original query worked well in that I was able to output the 'topic' and 'username' into a php table.  However, I need to have a third column for 'replies' or actually number of repies.  I figure if I can extract the 'idreply' for each 'topic' in the 'topics' table by a JOIN on r.idreply = t.idreply, I can count the number of an 'idreply' for each 'topic' and add it to my output as a third column.  I'm not sure how though??  I tried your recent suggestion but I'm getting an unexpected 'LEFT' (T_STRING) in error....tnx for your consideration!

Comment: @ksdst1 Edited my answer again. Regarding your error, I suspect, you forgot to remove the semicolon. Please have a try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT t.topic, t.idtopic, u.username
    FROM topics t 
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.idcat = c.idcat 
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.iduser = u.iduser 
WHERE t.idcat = '" . $idcat . "'"
```